# How to find out who was the friend request sender in a friendship?

Tags: facebook, friends

So lets say John Smith and John Doe are friends since 2010. Is there a way to find out whether John Smith or John Doe sent the friend request for this friendship in the first place?

Comment: Only the users in question can tell.

Comment: @Julio: Okay, let's assume one of them wants to know. How would he do it?

Comment: Check the notification email; in 2010 at least one of the users may have enabled email notification for friend requests..

Answer (score -2):

Check timeline for notification of this friendship.

Comment: Honestly? Scroll through 3+ years of items to find one?